# Using CSOM can i ensure the user using the login user id instead of the login username

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, modern-experience, external-users

I have the following CSOM code inside my remote event receiver:

```
ListItem listItem = context2.Web.GetList(context2.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/Assets").GetItemById(listItemID);
context2.Load(listItem);
context2.ExecuteQuery();
FieldUserValue creator = listItem["Author"] as FieldUserValue;

listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(context2.Web.EnsureUser(creator.LookupValue), new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context2) { contributeDef });
```

The above code will get a list item >> assign the author of the item inside the listitem permission. The code will work on 99% of the cases.. but we face this case:-

1. there is an internal user named `user.ABC`
2. there is another external user named also `user.ABC`

So my above code will always select the internal username, even if the author was the external user.

So can I improve my code by passing the user id to the `EnsureUser` method? or another way to assign the Author of a list item to the list item permission?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
User oUser = context2.Web.SiteUsers.GetByID(<user-id>);

listItem.RoleAssignments.Add(oUser, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context2) { contributeDef });
```

Replace `<user-id>` with actual ID of user.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so the <user-id> will be thr `creator.LookupID` ?

Comment: also does the `context2.Web.SiteUsers` only contain the users who have access to the web? or it includes all users inside the active directory ?

Comment: Yes, you can get user id by using `creator.LookupId`. It will give you the users who have access to the web. As you are using Author field so it should solve your purpose (user already has access to web as he/she is able to create list items).

Comment: also does the context2.Web.SiteUsers only contain the users who have access to the web? or it includes all users inside the active directory ?

Comment: **It will give you the users who have access to the web**. Did the code in my answered solve your isssue?

Comment: what do you mean by users whi have access to the web? so if i added the "Everyone except external " to the member grouup then the Web.SiteUsers will include all the internal users? based on my test it does not.. as in my case the Web.SiteUsers only included 11 users our of 250 user!

Answer (score 0):

@John John,

yes `creator.LookupID` is the user id. `SiteUsers` does not include all user inside the active directory. Its users come from a hidden user info list in the site collection. When a user establishes a relationship with this site(access the site/assigned with an item. etc), it will be resolved as a user item in the list.